# Weakly Cauchy sequences need not be weakly convergent

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weakly-cauchy-sequences

A sequence $(x_n)$ in a Banach space $X$ is called *weakly Cauchy* if for every $\ell \in X'$ the sequence $(\ell(x_n))$ is Cauchy in the scalar field.

> I want to show that weakly Cauchy sequences are not necessarily weakly convergent.

This seems to be the case for Hilbert spaces [On the limits of weakly convergent subsequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24577/on-the-limits-of-weakly-convergent-subsequences), whats the difference?

Comment: For a counterexample, consider the sequence $(y_n)$ defined by $y_n=e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n$ in $c_0$, where $e_i$ is the $i$'th standard unit vector. Spaces where weakly Cauchy sequences are weakly convergent are called *weakly sequentially complete*. Reflexive spaces are such spaces.

Comment: Thanks, Is it obvious that this is cauchy? $\ell(y_m) - \ell(y_n) = (0,0,...0,-1-1...0,...,0)$ or something? Where we have min(n,m) zeros in the beginning..? And why is it not weakly convergent? I guess $y = (1,1,1,1,1...1)$ what is the functional that makes $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ell(y_n) \rightarrow \ell(y)$ false?

Comment: For $m\ge n$ and $l=(l_1,l_2,\cdots)$, $l(y_m)-l(y_n)$ would have the form $\sum_{i=n+1}^m\ell_i$. But  $l$ is an element of $\ell_1$; thus absolutely summable...

Comment: For the second part of your comment, note that $(1,1,\ldots)$ (which is the only candidate for a weak limit point) is not an element of $c_0$.

Comment: But is it obvious that elements in $\ell_1$ gives a weakly cauchy ? And why does the weak limit point has to be in $c_0$. Please explain it seems like i missed something fundamental here.

Comment: Yes, it should be obvious that $(y_n)$ is weakly Cauchy. In fact, it's obvious that $(l(y_n))$ is a convergent sequence in $\Bbb K$ for any $l$ in $\ell_1$; since $l(y_n)$ is just the sum of the first $n$ coordinates of $l$. To address your second question: when one talks about a "limit point" of a sequence, that point needs to be in the same space as the elements of the sequence. Here, we are talking about a sequence in the space $c_0$. Any limit point (of any type) must be an element of $c_0$ as well.

Comment: I think I understand now, so $\sum_i |l_i| < \infty$ ? Im not used to thinking about functionals as coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the link, it's actually true for a reflexive space.

So to get a counter-example, we have to think on a non-reflexive Banach space.

Take $X:=C[0,1]$ endowed with the supremum norm and $x_n(t):=t^n$. This sequence [doesn't converge weakly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245536/weak-convergence-of-sequence-of-polynomials), but for all $l\in X'$, we can represent it by a Radon measure, and $\left\{\int_{[0,1]}t^d\mu(t)\right\}$ is convergent by monotone convergence theorem applied to the positive and negative parts of $\mu$.

Comment: I have not seen the Radon measures before. So since we can represent it by a Radon measure we have a weakly Cauchy sequence?

Comment: That right (actually, as $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ are complete, we have for all linear continuous functional that $\{L(x_n)\}$ is convergent.